# How to set css properties for "after" and "before" DOM psuedo elements

Tags: html, css

I need to change the color of "border-left" from red by default to color in scope (blue for example).

```css
.hello:before {
  content:' ';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 25px;
    position:absolute;
    border-left:3px solid red;
}
.hello:after {
    content:' ';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    position:absolute; 
    border-left:3px solid red;

}
```

```html
<div class="hello"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### example for single color

```
.hello.blue:before {
    border-color: blue;
}
.hello.blue:after { 
    border-color: blue;    
}

<div class="hello {{color}}"></div>
```

### example for any hexadecimal color code

use a embedded style, which may only work if you can put this in the  of your doc...

```
<style>
.hello:before {
    border-color: #{{color}};
}
.hello:after { 
    border-color: {{color}};    
}
</style>
```

and then set the $scope.color in the controller

Comment: Thank you again. But i need change border-color for ".hello:after" and for ".hello:before", not for ".hello" div.

Comment: I think you are going to have to use vanilla JS or possibly jQuery and move away from angular for this one thing...is that a problem?

Comment: oooh, just had an idea that may allow you to use angular still...using an embedded stylesheet instead of a separate file...I'm not sure what your controller looks like and what parts of the DOM it includes though...

Comment: Please, look this fiddle [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/p2xfu6ky/1/) i need to change the color (get in scope) for "right:after" and "right:before"

Comment: answer is updated, if this won't work, you would have to use JS/jQuery, I am pretty sure.